# Optimising a code in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

For a given positive integer y(y > 1), if we can find a largest integer k and a smallest positive integer x, such that x^k=y, then the power of y is regarded as k.

Calculate the sum of the power of the integers from a to b. (2<= a <= b <=10^18)

For each test case, there is one line containing two integers a and b.

End of input is indicated by a line containing two zeros.

Time limit: 11s

I made this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main (void)
{
    long long i,j,count;
    while (1)
    {
        cin>>i>>j;
        count = 0;
        if ( i!= 0 && j != 0 )
        {
            if ( i > 1 && j > 1 )
            {
                while ( i <= j )
                {
                    long long temp = -9999;
                    long long x = 2L;
                    long long k = 0L;
                    while ( temp != i )
                    {
                        temp = pow(x,k);
                        if ( temp > i )
                        {
                            x++;
                            k = 0;
                        }
                        else if ( temp == i )
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                            k++;
                    }
                    count = count + k;
                    i++;
                }
             cout<<count<<"\n";
            }
        }
        else if ( i == 0 && j == 0 )
            break;      
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, from 2 to till the number is obtained for which I have the required condition satisfied, I calculate the numbers. This is exceeding the time limit. Any better approach?

Thanks! :)

Edit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main (void)
{
    long long i,j,count;
    while (1)
    {
        cin>>i>>j;
        count = 0;
        if ( i == 0 && j == 0 )
            break;
        else
        {
            if ( i > 1 && j > 1 )
            {
                while ( i <= j )
                {
                    long long x = 2;
                    long long k = 1;
                    long long temp = 1;
                    while ( temp != i )
                    {
                        temp = temp*x;
                        if ( temp > i )
                        {
                            x++;
                            k = 1;
                        }
                        else if ( temp == i )
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                            k++;
                     }
                    count = count + k;
                    i++;
                }
            cout<<count<<"\n";
            }
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Made the changes. Need further optimization. Any suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just to make sure that everyone understands the problem in the same way, you should put here a sample output for two given values of a and b

Answer (score 2):

That kind of problem isn't solved by hacking code together. It is solved by *thinking* about the problem. What if I give you the numbers a = 2 and b = 10^18: How many numbers will you be examining? I get about 10^36. That should make it clear that there is some way that you can find by thinking that is a lot lot faster (because no computer in the world can do 10^36 calculations, and doing 10^18 calculations will keep a decent computer busy for a year).

Let's go directly at the case a = 2, b = 10^18. Almost all those numbers have power = 1. About a billion have power = 2. There are only about a million numbers with power >= 3, and you can find all of them very quickly. That should be enough of a hint.

Think about it: If your computer had an instruction that calculates the power of a number x in one nanosecond, and you added the power of the numbers from 2 to 10^18, how long would that take? So it's obvious that *this* is not the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As this seems to be homework, I won't give you an implementation, just a few tips:

- In the while loop, instead of using pow(x, k) for each iteration, you should use the fact that `x^(k+1) = x^k * x` (initialize temp cleverly and then multiply it by x on each iteration)
- Your two ifs are redundant, you can simply remove `if ( i!= 0 && j != 0 )` and leave the inner if
- To make your code cleaner and easier to read, you should declare functions. In this case, a function to compute the sum of the powers of X would isolate the inner while loop.
- You should check the validity of the input (`2<i<j<10^18`)

Have you also tried to write on a paper what two or three iterations of the algorithm would be?

Hint: http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumGeneralPowersNaturalNumbers.htm

Comment: *"To make your code cleaner and easier to read, you should declare functions. In this case, a function to compute the sum of the powers of X would isolate the inner while loop."* - in general, of course, but I'm not sure that's the best advice considering that the OP needs to get his run time down.  At least make sure that they're inlined.

Comment: Let the compiler inline the functions and decide what is faster. Clean code is always easier to optimise in my opinion.

Comment: Well, I've worked on image processing code wherein I had to tune some inner loops to get rid of function call overhead, so you can't always blindly trust the compiler to fix your potential problems.  It's rare (very rare) that I would recommend against using a function, but adding abstraction is certainly not going to be my first task when attempting to make a block of code *faster*

Comment: Yes, good advice to a professional who is already knowledgable about all that **and** no, bad advice to a student who is learning algorithms. In his case, what is wrong is the algorithm, no the code optimisation.